# How do I reuse a PDOStatement prepare?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I made a search but I couldn't find anything fulfilling

Imagine the following:

```
<?php

$connection = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$stmt1 = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
            a = :a
    AND     b = :b
    AND     c = :c
    AND     d = :d
    AND     search LIKE :search
");
$stmt1->bindValue(":a", $a);
$stmt1->bindValue(":b", $b);
$stmt1->bindValue(":c", $c);
$stmt1->bindValue(":d", $d);

$stmt2 = clone $stmt1;

$stmt1->bindValue(":search", "a%");
$stmt2->bindValue(":search", "b%");

$stmt1->execute();
$stmt2->execute();

while(($r1 = $stmt1->fetchObject()) && ($r2 = $stmt2->fetchObject()))
    echo $r1->foo . " " . $r2->foo . "\n";
}
```

Am I allowed to do something like this? How can I `clone`/reuse a `PDOStatement` instance and use it at the same time of its original instance?

Don't say *"use `UNION`"*, that's not the point of my question :P

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by clone ? using only the same statement or using the same parameters too !

Comment: You don't clone the `$stmt` object. You bind different values and then call ->execute() again (along with fetch).

Comment: Can't you just bind all 5 variables and execute it then rebind the `:search` variable and execute it again?

Comment: @N.B. how do bind different values and iterate over two recordsets **at the same time**? :P what you guys suggested can't work

Comment: @Tony i want to use both resultsets at same time

Comment: @Wes - if you take a look what you said - *iterate at the same time*. That means you have access to array/object of **both** queries. Now, why is that different than execute first query > fetch data, execute second query > fetch data, iterate when you have both arrays/objects?

Comment: Yeah, so you execute the first one and save the resultset then rebind `:search` and save the result set. Then you have 2 arrays or objects, or whatever you save. Or am I missing something?

Comment: you guys are talking of buffered resultsets, not unbuffered ones. I don't have the whole arrays: I just pick one row at once

Comment: note: the above code doesn't work, hence my question

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's buffered or not. If you follow the regular process of fetching data for both queries you've done (while..., save read row in array), in the end you'll end up with 2 arrays of data. It won't be parallel or anything nice like that and it will probably hang a bit, but you'll get those two you want to work with. It seems you're making a big deal out of something trivial, there's no need to clone anything, just execute the same prepared statement twice with different parameters and use a while loop in both cases to populate array(s) with data.

Comment: @Wes how big are the result sets? Why can't you read the entire resultset into an array? If space is an issue then read the entire first resultset? Also, I think `clone` is just for objects. I think `$stmt1 = $stmt2` is what you need to copy the query string. You don't need to copy it though if you read the first result set into an array, you can just rebind values.

Comment: guys, i know the alternatives, i'm just trying to understand the design of pdo, if there is a way to achieve this or if i'm doing something wrong :) thanks you both anyway!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not what prepared statement re-use is for. The idea of reusing a prepared statements is *consecutive*, not *concurrent*.

So you *can* do this:

```
$connection = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$stmt = $connection->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE a = :a
      AND b = :b
      AND c = :c
      AND d = :d
      AND search LIKE :search
");

$stmt->bindValue(":a", $a);
$stmt->bindValue(":b", $b);
$stmt->bindValue(":c", $c);
$stmt->bindValue(":d", $d);

foreach (["a%", "b%"] as $search) {
    $stmt->bindValue(":search", $search);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($r = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        echo $r->foo . "\n";
    }

    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

If you want to handle multiple result sets concurrently (at least with MySQL), you will need to do one of the following:

- Use an appropriate set of `UNION`/`JOIN` to create a single result set.
- Buffer the result sets in memory and iterate them again when you have all the data available.
- Create multiple *connections* - you cannot have more than one open statement cursor *per connection*, but you can have multiple open connections.

If you want to use multiple connections, your code becomes:

```
$query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE a = :a
      AND b = :b
      AND c = :c
      AND d = :d
      AND search LIKE :search
";

$connection1 = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$connection2 = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$stmt1 = $connection1->prepare($query);
$stmt1->bindValue(":a", $a);
$stmt1->bindValue(":b", $b);
$stmt1->bindValue(":c", $c);
$stmt1->bindValue(":d", $d);
$stmt1->bindValue(":search", "a%");

$stmt2 = $connection2->prepare($query);
$stmt2->bindValue(":a", $a);
$stmt2->bindValue(":b", $b);
$stmt2->bindValue(":c", $c);
$stmt2->bindValue(":d", $d);
$stmt2->bindValue(":search", "b%");

$stmt1->execute();
$stmt2->execute();

while(($r1 = $stmt1->fetchObject()) && ($r2 = $stmt2->fetchObject()))
    echo $r1->foo . " " . $r2->foo . "\n";
}

$stmt1->closeCursor();
$stmt2->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for an abstraction of a prepared statement that is able to carry it's own parameters with it.

As you actually consume each result by traversing it, adding an `Iterator` that knows how to traverse such a parametrized prepared statement looks fitting then.

However this suggestion is not part of PDO, so you would need to write it your own (however this might also prevent to repeat yourself with PDO code *and* you perhaps can even deffer the actual creation and execution of the statement so this might also create some benefit for lazy loading data).

Comment: that's what i was thinking to do :P